# Repeated Permutation

Tags: ruby

I know how to create permutations of an array of values. For example:

```
[*1..3].permutation(2)
```

which results in the following six permutations:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 1]
[2, 3]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
```

But this result is missing the three permutations, which are combinations of the same value, i.e.:

```
[1, 1]
[2, 2]
[3, 3]
```

How can I get all the permutations, including repeated ones above?

Comment: You asked for combinations but your example shows repeated permutations.  Do you need to see real combinations also, e.g. `[]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`, `[1,2]`, `[1,3]`, `[2,3]`, `[1,2,3]`?

Comment: Me too, are you sure you got the terminology right? Make sure to take your time learn what exactly the terms 'combination', 'permutation' and 'permutation with repetitions' mean.

Comment: ah i see, thanks.. it's "permutation with repetitions", i will edit my question.. ^^

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try [#repeated_permutation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation):

```
[*1..3].repeated_permutation(3).to_a

 > pp [*1..3].repeated_permutation(3).to_a
[[1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 3],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 3, 1],
 [1, 3, 2],
 [1, 3, 3],
 [2, 1, 1],
 [2, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 3],
 [2, 2, 1],
 [2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [2, 3, 2],
 [2, 3, 3],
 [3, 1, 1],
 [3, 1, 2],
 [3, 1, 3],
 [3, 2, 1],
 [3, 2, 2],
 [3, 2, 3],
 [3, 3, 1],
 [3, 3, 2],
 [3, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Very concise.

Answer (score 6):

I noticed your question asked for *combinations* but your example used *repeated permutations*.  If you are really interested in generating actual combinations, then a quick and dirty way to do this is:

```
>> x = [* ?a..?c]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
>> (0..x.length).each{|i| x.combination(i){|y| p y}}
[]
["a"]
["b"]
["c"]
["a", "b"]
["a", "c"]
["b", "c"]
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Oh no problem, just making sure. Starting in Ruby 1.9.1, `?a` is just `"a"`.  Before 1.9.1 it would have been 97.